# How do I display information submitted in a form back to the user?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2012

How do I display information submitted in a form back to the View in an MVC app using C# in Visual Studio 2012?  After the user clicks "Submit," I want the name to display in a message that confirms the info. was received.  Please note that I am only using the View and Controller right now, and not the Model.

Here is the View:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        <div>First Name @Html.TextBox("First Name")
             Last Name @Html.TextBox("Last Name")
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcCheeseSurvey.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I think you need to study MVC properly and look at the samples MSDN provides at http://www.asp.net/mvc/samples.

Comment: "I am only using the View and Controller right now, and not the Model." - That's the problem. If you were using Models, you could do your update/whatever, and then pass the Model right along to a new View that's in a confirmation/read-only mode to show the user what they entered in a different format. Go read up on "ViewModels" and this will be much more clear.

Comment: This is for homework.  I could have followed tuts using the full MVC, but that is not what the assign. calls for.  I suppose I'll use models too, since he didn't say we couldn't use models.

Comment: I should be able to pass a string that the user enters without using a Model, but how do I get it to go from the form to display back when the user presses "Submit"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your Text Box input names (remove spaces):

```
...
...
        @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        <div>First Name @Html.TextBox("FirstName")
             Last Name @Html.TextBox("LastName")
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
        }
...
...
```

Then add something like this in your controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index( string FirstName, string LastName )
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

The action marked with [HttpPost] will be used during Post and the input values are sent as Post parameters.